# interface key based on value of other key dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create dynamic key based on value of another key of the interface.

for example:

```
export interface IForm {
    form_control: string;
    based on the value of the form_control: string;
}

const form: IForm = {
    form_control: 'name',
    name: 'sample'
}
```

I want to do this just by interfaces and I do not want to create class to achieve this.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type for `IForm` in order to represent the constraint. Here's one way to do it:

```
export type IForm<K extends string> = { form_control: K } & Record<K, string>;
```

which uses the built-in [`Record<K, V>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1379-L1384) type meaning a type with keys in `K` and values `V`.

Then, to declare variables of type `IForm<K>` without having to manually specify the value of `K`, you can use type argument inference by making a helper function like this:

```
const asIForm = <K extends string>(iForm: IForm<K>) => iForm;
```

And use it like this:

```
const form = asIForm({
  form_control: 'name',
  name: 'sample'
}); // inferred as type IForm<"name">
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But for curiosity, is there a way just do this by interfaces? 
Since asForm is a function to create the const form.

Comment: Not generically, no.  Why do you need interfaces?

Comment: not for a particular reason, just for my knowledge. I wanted to know if there is a way to do this in just by assigning an interface. (const form: IForm = ... ).